# Как остановить setInerval при клике на кнопку и после его опять запустить?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Решил сделать слайдер, для навигации по слайдам использую три точки снизу, которые листают слайды. setInterval меняет слайды каждые 3 секунды, но если кликнуть на точку, например, на второй секунде, то таймер не перезапускается, он уже меняет слайд через секунду. Пробовал clearInterval, но он полностью останавливает слайдер. Как сделать так, чтобы setInterval начинал работать заново после клика?

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let dots = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__button');
let slideIndex = 0;

    function activeSlide(n) {
    for (let slide of slides) {
        slide.classList.remove('active');
    }

    slides[n].classList.add('active');
}

function activeDot(n) {
    for (let dot of dots) {
        dot.classList.remove('active');
    }

    dots[n].classList.add('active');
}

function currentSlide(index) {
    activeSlide(index);
    activeDot(index);
}

function nextSlide() {
    if (slideIndex == slides.length - 1) {
        slideIndex = 0;
        currentSlide(slideIndex) 
    }   else {
        slideIndex++;
        currentSlide(slideIndex) 
    }
}

dots.forEach((item, indexDot) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideIndex = indexDot;
        currentSlide(slideIndex);
    })
})

setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
```

Comment: Как вариант можешь остановить слайдер, когда навел мышь на слайдер, и запускать когда убрал мышь со слайда. Как сделать? товарищ ниже ответил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это должно выглядеть так:

```
let interval;

dots.forEach((item, indexDot) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideIndex = indexDot;
        currentSlide(slideIndex);
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
    })
})

interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает все как надо